# Potential energy between 2 moving charges

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, charge, potential-energy, voltage

Let's say we have 2 positive charges repelling each other along a line.
Initially they are pretty close and over time get far away from each other.
The key is that both charges are allowed to move and neither is fixed.
My question is whether the following claim is true (as I think it is) and if not, then please explain why not:
The total amount of work that the 2 charges will do on each other as each moves 1 meter equals to the amount of work that would have been done if one charge was fixed and the other moved 2 meters.
So if both are allowed to move and go to infinity away from each other, each will experience half the work as when one moves to infinity and the other is fixed. But the sum of the work in both cases though will be equal (0.5Wa + 0.5Wb = Wa when only A moves).
Thank you for your help!

PS
What I mean by twice the distance is that in the case when one is fixed, the other travelled twice as much as it would have travelled if both were allowed to move. But the total separation in the end position between the 2 charges is the same - it's just a question of whether one moved 2 meters and the other one 0, or both moved 1 meter.

Answer (score 1):

The change in electric potential energy of a system of two changes does not depend on how the charges were moved from their initial positions to their final positions.

With both charges able to move freely assume that the charges start at positions $+x_1$ and $-x_1$ on the $x$-axis and finish at positions $+x_2$ and $-x_2$.

The work done on one charge due to the force exerted by the other charge in both cases is an integral of the form $\displaystyle \int^{x_2}_{x_1} \dfrac{kq^2}{(2x)^2}dx = \dfrac 14 kq^2\left( \dfrac {1}{x_1}- \dfrac{1}{x_2}\right)$ where $x$ is the position of the particle as it moves from its initial position to the final position.
So the total work done by the system is $kq^2\left( \dfrac {1}{2x_1}- \dfrac{1}{2x_2}\right)$ and this is (minus) the change in potential energy of the system.

If one charge does not move then the work done on the charge which moves by the force exerted by charge which does not move is $\displaystyle \int^{2x_2}_{2x_1} \dfrac{kq^2}{x^2}dx = kq^2\left( \dfrac {1}{2x_1}- \dfrac{1}{2x_2}\right)$ where $x$ is the position of the moving particle relative to the stationary particle.